# Replace function replace everything, instead of a given index

Tags: python

I am a beginner, I try to write a program similar to hang man. I got stuck, because string is immutable, I can't find a way to solve this problem. I need help, please help me

```
words=("cat", "dog", "animal", "something", "whale", "crocodile", "lion", "summer", "boston", "seattle")
the_word=random.choice(words)
#print(the_word)
a=len(the_word) #number of words
blanks="_"*a
c=' '.join(blanks)#blanks seperated
print("This is a word with",a,"letter")
print("\t", c)
```

When I try to replace the error message appear, like c[0]="s"
I know there is replace function, I tried like this ipu=c.replace(c[0],"s"). 
When I print it, it turn out like this "s s s" It replace everything not just c[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't work with strings. Use lists and convert to strings when needed:

```
>>> c = ['_' for i in range(a)]
>>> c[0] = 's'
>>> ' '.join(c)
's _ _ _ _ _ _ '
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that `word` is the word to be guessed, and `guessed` the letters already tried by the player:

```
>>> guessed = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> word = 'cat'
>>> ' '.join (c if c in guessed else '_' for c in word)
'c a _'
>>> word = 'crocodile'
>>> ' '.join (c if c in guessed else '_' for c in word)
'c _ _ c _ _ _ _ _'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a real list instead of a string would be OK and do what you want here since all your input strings are short:

```
>>> blanks = ['_'] * 5
>>> ' '.join(blanks)
'_ _ _ _ _'
>>> blanks[1] = 'c'
>>> ' '.join(blanks)
'_ c _ _ _'
```